# Ethics of Plea Bargains

Tags: plea

Defendants are punished for exercising their right to trial - the State advocates for the harshest possible punishment unless the defendant enters into a plea bargain which requires the defendant to, under oath, waive their constitutional right(s).  Further, the trial adds several months of delay to the adjudication of her case.  So, the punishment is further multiplied.

Finally, how is it ethical for the State to conspire with a defendant to create and perpetuate a lie?  Plea bargains are lies - both the defendant and the prosecution know that the plea is something other than the truth yet they conspire to a falsehood and then go before a Judge swear that falsehood is truth under oath.

Seems shoddy.

Comment: This is a poorly-written question, and reads more like a rant. This isn't the place for a rant, so please try to keep your questions on-topic in the future.

Comment: @nomenagentis, If I say the sky is blue do I need a reference?  "Bargain"  -the lack of absolute truth is baked in to the term itself, right?  Ever heard "The truth, the WHOLE truth, and NOTHING BUT the TRUTH"?  This is sworn prior to stating the partial truth that is the plea BARGAIN.

Comment: How can one bargain what the truth is?  They can't.  Truth is truth.  Anything short of truth is not truth.  And if one specifies the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth, then they are going out of their way to proclaim this is the truth.  You know?  Nothing personal, man.  It just stinks, doesn't it?

Comment: So, you are saying that pleading must be to a lesser included, where the elements of the statute are satisfied - that a plea bargain cannot be made where the lesser included is not an exact match.  Well, why not answer so I can accept that!?

Comment: If the plea is required to be to a lesser included then confessing to it under oath would not, itself, be unethical (a sworn lie).  The threat of harsher punishment to force the plea bargain remains unethical in my view.

Comment: @RonRoyston a guilty plea is not a sworn confession.  Defendants do not plead under penalty of perjury.

Comment: Is a plea entered in to without the defendant being sworn in?

Comment: @RonRoyston One might argue that lying is unethical whether sworn in or not (therefore whether illegal or not).

Comment: This is not a question. However, the judge asks the defendant, in no uncertain terms, if this is his/her wish to enter into this agreement, that they are aware that in doing so they are giving up their right to mount a defense to the charges, on and on. If the defendant says anything aside from yes, then the judge denies the plea bargain and sets a trial date. Nobody is suborning perjury.

Comment: I don't understand how you have come to the utterly wrong determination that a plea bargain necessarily means someone is not telling the truth. A plea bargain gives a guilty party the opportunity to BARGAIN for a lesser sentence in exchange for judicial economy (i.e. not making the state go through the trial process). No innocent person should enter into a plea. Sometimes it's for a lesser included, often just for a minimum sentence.

Comment: @gracey209: The Judge, Baliff's, Court Building Owner, Court Reporter, Court Clerk, D.A., Court Prosecutor, and even your own attorney are all making a living off of your indictment.  Not guilty means income over.  When it comes to feeding ones self and ones family, there are no ethics involved.  Only a jury provides impartial judgement.  It is the court who pretends to covet the truth, dresses like bankers, and it is the court that will do whatever it takes to win, regardless of the truth.  You speak from inexperience and ignorance.  The court is a terrorist anti-christian organization.

Comment: @royRoyston....You're either totally out of your mind or you're just trying to be antagonistic. Either way, you are missing the point: the DEFENDANT decides whether or not to take a plea. Nobody forces him/her into it. That sort of negates whatever logic you are attempting here. Next time you get arrested for bombing a planned parenthood or whatever you do in your spare time, tell the judge you don't agree with the plea, and you'll get your trial.

Comment: It is you who are speaking antagonistically, e.g. "out of your mind", "utterly wrong", "totally out of your mind", "next time you bomb", etc.  Calm down and think.  If you are starving and a man in a decorated suit offers you $5 to have sex with a donkey.  What are you going to do?

Comment: @gravey209, think about it.  Saying "nobody forces" the defendant into taking a plea is absurd--threatening years of prison *is* forcing someone to take  a plea.  Most rational people who are innocent will take a plea bargain.  You are suborning perjury by telling even innocent people that if they don't plead guilty they will go to prison for years if they don't plea.

Comment: @gracey209 Exactly!  Further, the defendant has to stand in front of the Judge and answer "No" to "Has anyone coerced you into this plea."  It's so awful...  Public at large is so very ignorant to these issues.  Heck, this entire forum refuses to discuss it citing 'opinion based'.  ...Ri-dick-eh-luss

Answer (score 5):

In short: Plea bargain benefit society as a whole.

If a defendant exercises his/her constitutional right to a jury trial, the trial takes up a lot of time and preparation. A jury trial costs a significant amount of time and money. Additionally, judges have to set aside court time for the trial, when instead they could be doing other things. In most states where there are elected judges, judges want to have a large number of criminal convictions, ie. Plea deals so they can say they are tough on crime. In states with appointed judges, judges will get promoted based on their number of finished cases in a year or their efficiency.

For prosecutors, they favor plea agreements because a plea agreement removes any chance the defendant will have his/her conviction overturned. When one agrees to a plea one waives any and all right to appeal one's conviction; otherwise, all defendants are guaranteed at least one appeal, which are once again expensive. Additionally, defendants can petition for habeas corpus. When they plead guilty the government won't have to defend against these petitions.

Defendants win because they get a lower sentence.

In the end pleas are ethical because they help society as a whole making the system more efficient. The criminals who plead serve their time and cannot get their convictions overturned.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45481/discussion-on-answer-by-viktor-ethics-of-plea-bargains).

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, the criminal justice system should:

- provide justice (fair and impartial)
- provide consistency (similar facts should receive similar sentences)
- be efficient (in time and money)
- provide fitting punishment and/or restitution (society needs its vengeance tempered by mercy)
- act as a deterrent (society needs protection)

Some of these aims are in direct conflict; for example, justice is expensive in both time and money.

As an officer of the court a DA will not bring a case to trial unless they have a genuine belief in the accused's guilt *and* a reasonable expectation of proving it.

Plea bargains benefit society be reducing the cost of justice, both in the courts and in corrections (shorter or no custodial sentences). They benefit the guilty by reducing their costs and punishment. They do not impact on the innocent because they can choose to go to trial.

**Edit re comment**

The OP commented:

> Well thought out, but, as you know nobody can define what justice is (e.g. Socrates, Plato). The courts provide no consistency nor are they efficient (or ever on time). They never provide fitting punishment. However, they do act as a deterrent, I'll agree to that. That said, the scope of this question regards plea bargains. Why is someone punished for choosing to not give up his constitution right to trial. If you ask how they are punished the answer is that a harsher penalty is advocated for and approved of by the State and the case remains open for additional months or even years.

As comments are transient, I thought it worth addressing some of the issues this raises in an edit.

I will just ignore the fact that my answer deals with an "ideal" justice system while the comment criticises the actual justice system. Any real system will fail to achieve the ideal because it requires fallible people and limited resources to implement a real system. Notwithstanding, the ideal system proposed has inherently conflicting objectives and any realisation *of necessity* requires a compromise between them.

"nobody can define what justice is" - not true [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/justice) is dictionary.com's definition; other dictionaries provide consistent definitions. In the specific instance of a criminal trial, justice involves being treated equally and impartially and being allowed to know the case against you and mount a defence. Plea bargaining does not in any way infringe this.

"The courts provide no consistency" and "They never provide fitting punishment" - you *really* need to read some judgements before making a claim like this. When a judge sentences someone, except for very minor offences (which are not the type of things that attract plea bargains anyway), they *must* write down their reasons for the sentence given. This provides both consistency as these reasons will refer to the punishments in other cases and "fitting punishments" as, if the reasons given do not support the sentence then both the defence and the prosecution have a right to appeal it. Read the judgements; don't rely on media hyperbole. A judgement exists to set out the judge's reasoning; a media report exists to sell advertising and cater to the prejudices of their audience.

"nor are they efficient (or ever on time)" - Second point first; my experience is that a judge sets the date and time allocation for a trial based on what the prosecution and the defence agree is achievable. In general, they are not too bad at this. Delays happen, but they happen in the construction industry, the logistics industry and the manufacturing industry as well.

"Efficient" means achieving the objectives at the lowest possible cost and is a question of management rather than justice. It is inefficient to have so few courts and judges that the wait for a trial date is "too long" (whatever you decide that means). Equally, it is inefficient to have so many that some are standing idle for large periods of time. Most real justice systems fail on the side of having too few resources but ultimately that is a political decision, not a legal one. Suffice to say I will refer you to the concept of the Time-Cost-Quality triangle of management - changing one of the sides of that triangle *always* has an impact for good or ill on the others.

"they do act as a deterrent" - I'm on a roll here because I'm going to disagree with you on this too. Many studies have shown that the severity of a sentence has an infinitesimal impact on a perpetrator's decision to commit a crime. Of far more significance is the perception the perpetrator has on their chance of being caught irrespective of the likely sentence; efficient policing is more important than the sanction.

You say in your question "Defendants are punished for exercising their right to trial", however, this could be stated equivalently as "Defendants are rewarded for waiving their right to trial". By giving up their right they receive compensation but are under no compulsion to do so. If it is a good deal they will take it, if its a bad deal they will reject it; something for something is not unethical.

Comment: Well thought out, but, as you know nobody can define what justice is (e.g. Socrates, Plato). The courts provide no consistency nor are they efficient (or ever on time).  They never provide fitting punishment.  However, they do act as a deterrent, I'll agree to that.  That said, the scope of this question regards plea bargains.  Why is someone punished for choosing to not give up his constitution right to trial.  If you ask how they are punished the answer is that a harsher penalty is advocated for and approved of by the State and the case remains open for additional months or even years.

Comment: The definition of justice you posted says "the quality of being just."  Like I said - noone can define what justice is.  I image we agree that rulings of elected Judges are always polluted.  Regarding appointed Judges, the rulings are supposed to be in accordance with statutes which are crafted by elected officials, so their rulings are polluted at origin.  Regarding criminal courts, their effect is terror and terror is measured in seconds, not minutes, hours, days, weeks, months, or much less years.  Regarding plea bargains, do you negotiate with terrorists?  That is the question.

Comment: Regards negotiating with terrorists, of course you do if the prospective outcome is better than the alternative. The British did, that's why there is a United States of America.

Comment: if everyone refused plea bargains, i.e., refused to negotiate, what would happen?

Comment: my comments here aren't transient, looks like others are as mine are the only one remaining.  Dale I appreciate your long winded answer but you're wrong on may points.  I kinda promised myself I would stop contributing to this particular SE because it's far too censored.  No doubt moderated by people who believe they are smarter than the rest, - lawyers.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers appear to assume a utilitarian ethics and argue that plea bargains are beneficial to society (cost, efficiency, etc.) and therefore ethical. However, they fail to address what I feel is the real concern here: the deontological position that it is unethical to believe one thing (the defendant is guilty of murder) but do another (punish the defendant as though the defendant is guilty of manslaughter).

One way out of this particular problem might be to rethink what a plea bargain really is. Instead of the plea bargain being understood as implying something about the crime, we can instead see a plea bargain as a modification of the punishment. In this way of thinking, acceptance of a plea bargain would be more similar to a confession of guilt to the true crime than to some lesser crime, and the reduced sentence simply leniency on the part of the prosecutor and judge.

If the leniency aspect is still troubling, you might even consider that typical sentencing guidelines assume that the case will go to trial and consist of two parts: one part related to the actual crime, and one part related to the "meta-crime" of failing to confess to a crime of which you knew you were guilty. This introduces some difficulty for punishments that seem incommensurate - like jail vs. death - but you might be able to escape from that difficulty by applying some utility function to the punishments which normalize them to some sort of standard measure (e.g., "death" is really just like being in prison until you die of natural causes, or that plus some extra, etc.)

Comment: Best answer so far, for sure.  Plea bargains fly in the face of truth.  #1:Lady Justice is blind and #2:Two wrongs do not make a right.  So I, at least, take issue with the deceptive use of terms such as Law, and Truth, and Whole Truth in a courtroom.  The fact that the Judge dresses up an an executioner/angel of death (black robe) does not go unnoticed but men who study meaning know the criminal court is an anti-Christian terrorist organization, (forgiveness).  Lastly, prison does not equate with death.  What would you call it if you put a dog in a tiny cage but kept it alive with food?

Comment: @RonRoyston Thanks for the vote of confidence. If you feel this is the best answer, feel free to upvote and/or accept it so that others with similar questions can find it. FWIW, I thought it was a very interesting question and wasn't entirely satisfied by the other answers either.

Comment: This answer is rooted in a false and unprovable premise, "*it is unethical to **believe** one thing...but do another*" Who is doing the ***believing***? The prosecutor? Since when is the prosecutor the sole determinant of truth? The judge? The judge is sworn to believe the accused is innocent until proven guilty. The jury? There is no jury without a trial. The public? Since when is trial by public opinion acceptable? So who is this ***believer*** in your premise?

Comment: @Mowzer The prosecutor, I suppose, believes the accused is guilty of the greater offense, but is willing to accept a plea to a lesser offense. I do not say the prosecutor is the sole determiner of truth, but surely the prosecutor has reason to believe the defendant is guilty of the greater crime if the prosecutor is otherwise willing to prosecute the case. I don't think it's at all unreasonable to question the ethics of a prosecutor who firmly believes the defendant is guilty of a greater crime, but accepts a plea bargain for a lesser crime. That's not to say I think it's unethical - see anwer

Comment: @RonRoyston - just saw the last part of your comment. My utility function is just an example - we could probably find a much better way to compare seemingly incomparable punishments. You get the idea though. Regarding the angel of death / anti-Christian charge, I hadn't thought about that, but upon reflection I think there's definitely merit to that. That said, I don't think this question/answer/comment section is the right place to discuss that.

Comment: Based on your comment to me, it's clear your answer **only addresses** the ethics of the **prosecutor's behavior** and not the ethics of the plea bargain itself. With that added clarity, let me ask you this question. Where does ***prosecutorial discretion*** factor into your analysis? The prosecutor is not obligated to prosecute any particular crime regardless of his personal beliefs about it. So is it unethical for a prosecutor to exercise prosecutorial discretion and decline prosecuting a suspect for a crime of which the prosecutor personally believes the suspect is guilty?

Comment: @Mowzer We might want to take this to chat to avoid clutter. In brief: of course it's the prosecutor who's being unethical; plea bargains are a thing, and things can't behave unethically because they simply are. I don't know specifics about *prosecutorial discretion*, but I could see it going either way depending on the degree to which the discretion is exercised partially (based on whims, prejudices, personal motives, etc.) or impartially (based on the evidence at hand). Why shouldn't a prosecutor prosecute a crime? Personal beliefs not based on evidence sound like prejudices - by definition.

Comment: *Prosecutorial discretion refers to the fact that under American law, government prosecuting attorneys have nearly absolute powers. A prosecuting attorney has power on various matters including those relating to choosing whether or not to bring criminal charges, deciding the nature of charges, plea bargaining and sentence recommendation. This discretion of the prosecuting attorney is called prosecutorial discretion.* ([Source](http://definitions.uslegal.com/p/prosecutorial-discretion/)) In other words, plea bargains are both legal and ethical under our system of justice.

Comment: @Mowzer The question is clearly asking about some other kind of ethics since I don't think anybody so far has questioned the legality of plea bargains. I imagine the question could be broadened to *prosecutorial discretion* without much loss in meaning - the issue is basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with multiple premises of this question.

Faulty premise #1

> Defendants are punished for exercising their right to trial

The rest of that sentence fails to logically support this assertion.

Faulty premise #2

> Further, the trial adds several months of delay to the adjudication of her case. So, the punishment is further multiplied.

The trial doesn't **add** delay. The plea bargain **reduces** the time it would take to go to trial.

Faulty premise #3

> Plea bargains are lies

All plea bargains are not a lie.

Comment: #1, maybe.  #2 I see your point but being told that you could gain immediate relief by waiving your constitutional rights is a slight/insult unto itself, i.e., a punishment, and #3 insofar as the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth is to be measured plea bargains are lies.  Also, regarding #2, speedy trial is a fallacy.  Anyone who ever followed any case knows that.

Comment: @RonRoyston: #1: Okay. #2: What rights are you waiving? You are exercising your right to due process by entering into a plea bargain aren't you? #3: "The truth..." is the witness oath. Trials are about outcomes based on proof. Which are completely subjective and risky propositions. And the term ***speedy trial*** has a ***legal definition***. This is different than your ***personal definition*** — which seems to be the informational basis of your question.

Comment: Due process is the legal requirement that the state must respect all legal rights that are owed to a person.  Offering immediate relief to those willing to give up a portion of their legal rights is itself a violation of due process.  Respect is a feeling of deep admiration for someone or something, in this case a jury trial.  If I respect a woman, I don't offer her $500 to show me her boobies.  If I respect a decision, I don't ask for reconsideration.  If I respect a right, I don't ask one to give it up.

Comment: @RonRoyston: Your premise is flat wrong. You don't give up your right to a trial with a plea bargain. You trade that right in exchange for a negotiated outcome. That's where the word ***bargain*** comes from in the term ***plea bargain***. The certain outcome has greater value to defendant than the right of trial with an uncertain outcome. For example, if you buy something from the store with the money in your pocket, you don't ***give up*** that money, you use that money to trade for something of equal or greater value to you. To see it as ***giving up*** the money is just wrong thinking.

Comment: grasping semantics is important.  They don't say 'trade' your right to trial; they say 'waive' your right to trial.  Waive: to officially say that you will not use or require something that you are allowed to have or that is usually required.  You don't waive the money in your pocket nor do you trade it.  You spend it.

Comment: @RonRoyston: ***Spending*** money is equivalent to ***trading*** it for something of equal or greater value... by definition! Similarly, you ***waive*** your right as part of the process of ***trading*** it for a certain outcome. I'm starting to suspect you're not engaging me in this conversation in good faith. Am I correct? Is this a joke? Are you putting me on and the members of and visitors to this site who read this question?

Comment: Spending money and trading are not equivalent, especially in a legal context.  I recommend you spend more time studying English at http://english.stackexchange.com/.  Once you have mastered the language, come back and give law a try.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Okay. For the record FWIW, I think @RonRoyston is putting us all on.

Comment: Mowzer, you are not us.  You are someone.  Comments should be about law discussion.  Please read the [help center's section on commenting](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).  I am happy to help Mowzer.

Comment: Personally, the current practice by many prosecutors of just piling on as many criminal charges as possible hoping to get a defendant to plea bargain to one of them is deplorable. Society benefits by this? Society is harmed by this. It's called 'moral hazard' and the unintended consequences are that when this becomes commonplace fewer and fewer people will respect the legal system. It's self destructive.

Comment: @markb: No where in my answer did I defend any of the moral hazard behaviors you described. In fact, I agree with you.

Comment: My mistake. I didn't mean to post this on your answer. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

As in other disciplines, so much about Law involves "holding one's nose."

The Law is a pure thing, an abstract ideal, which is then polluted by the unrelenting onslaught of pragmatics.

A nice example of this is our current-day patent law...where unscrupulous patent mills gin up generic broad patents, and litigate, extracting licensing agreements from the REAL tech companies because, frankly, it's going to cost less cash money to pay for a sham license than it is to fight it in court, and the likelihood of getting costs awarded is almost nil.

Another nice example:  the class-action shareholder/proxy suit, following any kind of corporate acquisition.  There is an unscrupulous law firm out there that will gin up a shareholder class-action, knowing that it's specious and unfounded, and the goal is to use the legal system to extract a pound of flesh from an innocent drive-by-shooting-target.

The problem with all of this is that the conservative "holy grail" of tort reform does not solve the problem, or rather, throws the baby out with the bathwater...so it's not going away anytime soon.

Comment: I agree with you regarding the stench.  It seems like law, in the scientific sense, is not an abstract ideal but a practical reality.  I think these lawyers stole the term 'law'.  In fact, laws cannot be broken.  If they could, they would be called principles!

Comment: How does this answer the only question that is asked - _how is it ethical for the State to conspire with a defendant to create and perpetuate a lie?_ Please attempt to answer it, or your answer risks deletion. This site isn't a place for rants, so if you do _get started_, it's not going to be looked favourably upon.

Comment: @jimsug, can you answer, or are you merely here to criticize?  Before you go about deleting content, consider that views that conflict with yours should be invited and considered rather than quenched.

Comment: @ron I'm here to request clarification from the author. I suggest you review the [help] and the purpose of comments. If you aren't able to take constructive criticism, this site may not be right for you.

Comment: @ron further, this isn't a site for opinions to stand on their own - they must be part of a question or answer. I certainly don't know how you inferred that I would delete this post because its views conflict with mine, since I haven't expressed any views on the topic.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I have exactly answered the question.  The answer is that pragmatics trump ethics.  That's the answer, full stop.  That's strictly NOT opinion.

Answer (score -1):

[The answer the OP indicated the OP liked best](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/5003/794) is limited to prosecutorial behavior during the plea bargain process and not the plea bargain itself. (See comments.) So let me call your attention to the concept of ***prosecutorial discretion***.

http://definitions.uslegal.com/p/prosecutorial-discretion/

> Prosecutorial discretion refers to the fact that under American law, government prosecuting attorneys have nearly absolute powers. A prosecuting attorney has power on various matters including those relating to choosing whether or not to bring criminal charges, deciding the nature of charges, plea bargaining and sentence recommendation. This discretion of the prosecuting attorney is called prosecutorial discretion. [Link to source](http://definitions.uslegal.com/p/prosecutorial-discretion/).

In other words, plea bargains are both **legal** and **ethical behavior** for prosecutors under our system of justice.

Comment: -1 I like that this answer tackles prosecutorial discretion directly, since I think that's where the OP's issue really is, but I think it's pretty weak to conclude that it's ethical because it's legal. Certainly the OP knows it's legal. The OP is asking about philosophy of law, specifically, is prosecutorial discretion morally/ethically justifiable? To properly answer, you should pick an moral/ethical theory (or several) and analyze. For instance, it certainly seems fine from a utilitarian viewpoint, but a Kantian viewpoint might require nuance to interpret the behavior as ethical.

Comment: @Mowzer, a prosecutors mandate varies by Jurisdiction.  There is no blanket mandate for USA lawyers.  Right, or no?  For example, in 'Texas', "It shall be the primary duty of all prosecuting attorneys, including any special prosecutors, not to convict, but to see that justice is done. " [link](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/CR/htm/CR.2.htm)  Obviously, this is not useful or used, but it is what they purport to operate under, knowing that they don't even know what Justice is.